# css is cutting off text

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue with a site

The text inside the article is cut off and whatever i try it will not show correctly. It gets cut off in the middle
Obviously i want to use the full size of that box (div)

The part in question is

```
<div class="text_blue">
<div class="text_blue_header">It takes a virtual village.</div>
<div class="text_blue_main">You. Us. Our partners in the know. We are a forward-    
thinking creative agency with big ideas. All we want is for you to look good, be 
successful and outsmart your competition. This is our site.</div>
</div>
```

The site has been build in Joomla with the T3 Framework

Anyone has an idea how to get that fixed?

Comment: The question, to be of any use to future visitors, should contain the relevant code, including CSS code, needed to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
height: 80px;
```

of the rule

```
.fixel-grid .items.text .article_content .article-intro
```

in the template.css line 5243

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem. Should have seen it myself :9